# Load all slack members into a var in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, slack

I would like to develop a JS code for the Slack Webapp. In this code I need a var that contains the list of all members as vector of strings. How do I load this var in a dev console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to https://SLACK.slack.com/threads/team/ (replace SLACK with your slack group name)

Enter this in the console, it will scroll through the sidebar and insert the members from the sidebar into an array called storage

```
var storage = [];
var el = document.querySelector('#team_list_scroller');
el.scrollTop = 0;
var last_scroll;
var loop = () => {
  last_scroll = el.scrollTop;
  el.scrollTop += 30;
  storage = storage.concat(
    Array.prototype.map.call(
      document.querySelectorAll('#team_list_scroller .member_details'),
      (el) => {
        let q = el.innerText.match(/\@\w+\W/);
        if ( q && !q.length ) return '';
        return q === null ? q = '@' + el.innerText.trim() : q[0].trim();
      }
    ).filter(t => t.length && t[0] === '@' && storage.indexOf(t) < 0)
  );

  if (el.scrollTop !== last_scroll) {
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  } else {
    console.log(storage);
  }
};
loop();
```

Comment: @catfishery added another line of code which will load the names from the team directory sidebar when you are on https://SLACK.slack.com/threads/team/

Comment: Nice addition, however it only loads some of the members for some reason. Also I am sorry but I forgot to mention that I need the @handles, not the displaynames.

Comment: @catfishery you can try it now, it scroll through the list and takes the currently displayed names and stores them in the variable storage

Comment: Thank you for the addition @richie ! Works like charms. However for some reason it skips the people who don't have a name set, just a handle.

Comment: @catfishery made some changes, it should work fine now

Comment: I had an error message:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    at storage.concat.Array.map.call (<anonymous>:11:44)
    at NodeList.map (native)
    at loop (<anonymous>:9:25)
    at <anonymous>:21:1

Comment: @catfishery updated the code again to handle cases where no handle seems to be found in the elements which are looped

Comment: @catfishery I should have checked for null cases of the RegExp as well, you can try the latest version now. It works fine for me.

Comment: It works again! Thank you! Unfortunately it still skips the handle-only members. I would like to accept your answer, do you still want to work on it?

Comment: @catfishery I have no slack group with handle-only members so I have no idea how to extract that data from the webpage. This is the best I can do at the moment.

Comment: Thank you! I am very happy with this code. Actually only around 10% of the people are missing this way. Easy to handle!

Comment: @catfishery I created a new slack user today with no name and rewrote the code a little to include those members as well. You can test it if you want.